# How to add up different numbers in a list?

Tags: python

I need to add up some numbers in a list.
For example I want a list like [1,3] to turn into [4] and if it's possible turn the list into a string.
So far i've tried:

```
list._add_(list)
```

But that just turns [1,3] into [1,3,1,3]

Comment: what does `if it's possible turn the list into a string` mean? Do you  want to change the ints to strings? Or maybe join them as one string?

Comment: can u also tell some number, if there any condition to skip numbers??

Comment: I probably didn't explain that very well so never mind about the string bit I got a good answer so thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use built-in [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sum) function:

```
sum([1,3])
4
```

Answer (score 0):

Can use `lambda` and `reduce` function also:

```
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, [1,2])
3
```

Normal Iterator method:

```
>>> l = [1,2,3]
>>> add_all = 0
>>> for i in l:
...     add_all += i
... 
>>> print add_all
6
```

Answer (score 0):

Not fully sure what turning into strings means:

```
l = [1,3]
```

Using [sum](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum):

```
print([sum(l)]) # sum and wrap in a list
[4]
```

Using [map](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map):

```
print(map(str,l)) # map from int to string, same as [str(x) for x in l]
['1', '3']
```

using [str.join](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_join.htm):

```
print("".join([str(x) for x in l]) # again map to str and join into a single string

13
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just create your own function:

```html
def addList (l):
    total=0
    for i in l:
        total=total+i

#Convert no. to string
return str(total)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use:

```
str(sum(your_list))
```

It will return the string value of the sum of numbers in the list.